# Update a field and track the date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to update the URL in my tbl 1 with URL tbl 2 if there isn't any. Also if the update takes place I want to add a custom to the date field in my tbl1 for that record. How can I modify the date to a custom to only those records where the change takes place?

```sql
select 
    t1.id, 
    t1.name,
    t1.age, 
    t1.location, 
    coalesce(t1.url,t2.url) as url,
    t1.date 
from 
    tbl1 t1 
full join tbl2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

```
tbl1
id, name, age, location, url, date
1, nick, 11, usa, 4444, , 06-01-2020
2, duke, 22, uk, 5555, yahoo, 06-01-2020
3, nate, 66, uk, 5552, aol,  05-02-2020
```

```
tbl2
id, url, field1, field2, field3, field4
1, google, x, x, x, x
2, yahoo,  , , , ,
5, ghub, , , , , ,
```

```
output
id, name , age , location, url, date
1,  nick, 11   , usa,  google, 06-08-2021
2,  duke, 22   , uk ,  yahoo, 06-01-2020
3,  nate, 66   , uk ,  aol,   05-02-2020
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you just need to update your table *only* where the `url` is null, in which case just join the tables on their `id` and specify that condition in the `where` clause

```
update t1 set
    t1.url=t2.url,
    t1.[date]=GetDate()
from 
tbl1 t1 join tbl2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id
where t1.url is null and t2.url is not null
```